# How to add <div> with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

is it possible to add an HTML code to HTML with javascript.?

because I have this code, it generated automatically like this:

```
<div class="investi-announcements-summary" data-investi-date-format="dd MMM yyyy" data-investi-num-announcements="100" data-investi-filter-regex=".*presentation">
   <div>28 Jun 2021</div>
   <h4><a href="http://www.example.com" target="_blank">Investor Presentation - June 2021</a></h4>
</div>
```

And I want to add this code `<div class="content">` before `<div>28 Jun 2021</div>` and this code `</div>` after `<h4></h4>`

so it'll be like this:

```
<div class="investi-announcements-summary" data-investi-date-format="dd MMM yyyy" data-investi-num-announcements="100" data-investi-filter-regex=".*presentation">
   <div class="content">
     <div>28 Jun 2021</div>
       <h4><a href="http://www.example.com" target="_blank">Investor Presentation - June 2021</a></h4>
   </div>
</div>
```

if it's possible, I hope someone can help me on that.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. In this particular example you can replace `innerHTML` of outer `div.investi-announcements-summary` with newly created `div`:

```js
const box = document.querySelector(".investi-announcements-summary"),
      newDiv = document.createElement("div");

newDiv.className = "content";

/* copy content of original div */
newDiv.innerHTML = box.innerHTML;

/* replace content of original div with new div */
box.innerHTML = newDiv.outerHTML;

document.getElementById("res").value = box.outerHTML;
```

```css
body
{
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="investi-announcements-summary" data-investi-date-format="dd MMM yyyy" data-investi-num-announcements="100" data-investi-filter-regex=".*presentation">
   <div>28 Jun 2021</div>
   <h4><a href="http://www.example.com" target="_blank">Investor Presentation - June 2021</a></h4>
</div>

<textarea id="res" readonly="true" style="width: 100%; height: 50%"></textarea>
```

But you should check out some tutorials on how to [add/replace DOM elements](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-make-changes-to-the-dom)

Answer (score 1):

```js
const mainEl = document.querySelector('.investi-announcements-summary')

let contentEl = document.createElement('div')
contentEl.classList.add('content')

for (let child of mainEl.children) contentEl.appendChild(child.cloneNode(true))

mainEl.innerHTML = ''
mainEl.appendChild(contentEl)
```

```html
<div class="investi-announcements-summary" data-investi-date-format="dd MMM yyyy" data-investi-num-announcements="100" data-investi-filter-regex=".*presentation">
   <div>28 Jun 2021</div>
   <h4><a href="http://www.example.com" target="_blank">Investor Presentation - June 2021</a></h4>
</div>
```